# SQL Union 1 Column within Larger Query with Laravel ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, union

I'm currently storing `addresses` for multiple different objects. So there is `addresses` for `jobs`, `companies`, etc.

I want to be able to get all `addresses.*` and a union of `jobs.job_title` & `companies.company_name` to select an `object_name` for each `addresses` record.

Address.php (Model)

```
static $object_type = [ 
    1 => 'Company',
    2 => 'Job',
];

static public function getObjectTypes() {
    return self::$object_type;
}

static public function getObjectTypeName($key) {
    return self::$object_type[$key];
}

static public function getAddresses(){

    $addresses = Address::select(
        'addresses.*'
    )->where('addresses.soft_deleted', 0);

    $addresses->limit(20);

    return $addresses->get();

}
```

The current schema for `addresses` table:

`+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(12) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| object_id         | int(12)             | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| object_type       | tinyint(3)          | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| address           | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| soft_deleted      | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created_at        | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

The current schema for `jobs` table:

`+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(12) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id      | int(12)             | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| job_title       | varchar(99)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| soft_deleted    | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created_at      | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

The current schema for `companies` table:

`+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(12) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_name    | varchar(99)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| soft_deleted    | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created_at      | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

My question is: How would I create the union and return the data needed based on the above structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bbe2/3) of what I *think* you are after.  This is a very simplified schema to illustrate what is being done:

```
addresses
id | objectId | objectType | address
1 | 1 | 1 | 4657
2 | 1 | 3 | 3465
3 | 2 | 4 | 4536
4 | 1 | 2 | 3098
5 | 2 | 1 | 5647
6 | 2 | 2 | 8989
7 | 1 | 4 | 4563
8 | 2 | 3 | 2345

companies
id | name
1 | 'Acme Anvils'
2 | 'McBarfles'
3 | 'Noke'
4 | 'Stab Mart'

jobs
id | companyId | title
1 | 4 | 'Fly Swatter'
2 | 3 | 'Palm Greaser'
3 | 2 | 'McBarfle Burger Tender'
4 | 1 | 'Shill'
```

Assuming that `objectType 1` = `Company` and `objectType 2` = `Job`:

```
SELECT 
  'Company' AS objectType,
  c.name,
  a.address
FROM addresses a
INNER JOIN companies c 
  ON a.objectId = c.id
WHERE a.objectType = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'Job' AS objectType,
  j.title,
  a.address
FROM addresses a
INNER JOIN jobs j
  ON a.objectId = j.id
WHERE a.objectType = 2
```

This breaks the joins up into sections based on the objectType in the addresses table, then `UNION ALL`s the results together to get the final list of addresses and object names:

```
objectType | name                   | address
Company    | Acme Anvils            | 4657
Company    | Noke                   | 3465
Company    | McBarfles              | 3098
Company    | Stab Mart              | 4563
Job        | Shill                  | 4536
Job        | Fly Swatter            | 5647
Job        | Palm Greaser           | 8989
Job        | McBarfle Burger Tender | 2345
```

Note that you would have to manually add additional queries to be `UNION ALL`ed for each possible value of `objectType`.

Comment: That's great Paul - thank you. I'm just going to accept your answer. I appreciate you taking the time to do this.